# How to share data among services in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I created two service classes. Below is the ShellService class definition.

```
class ShellService {

  create(data, params) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current)));
    }
    let hostname=params.query.hostname
    let port = params.query.port
    const id = _.uniqueId();

    this.shells[id] = spawn('mongo', ['--host', hostname, '--port', port]);

    return Promise.resolve({id});
  }
...
}
module.exports = function() {
  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  let service =new ShellService()

  return service;
};
```

In its create method, it creates a shell instance and add it on its shells array object. I have another rest service class and want to access the shells array object. How can I do that? I tried below but not work:

```
const shellService = require('../shell-service')
class SocketService {
  ...
```

I declared `SocketService` class and require the shell service. But I can't call `shellService.XXXX` in my `SocketService` class. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to explicitly initialize `shell-service` class? or is it fine, if you can just access its method statically?

Comment: I don't want to use it statically. Is there a way to get its instance in SocketService?

Comment: `create` needs to return different instance, every single time it gets invoked. Only, the logic for creating is same. Am I right about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already storing the shell reference in `this.shells[id]` you probably want to implement a `.find` [service method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html) that returns a list of all available shells:

```
class ShellService {
  find() {
    const shellProcesses = this.shells;
    const shells = Object.keys(shellProcesses).map(key => {
      const shell = shellProcesses[key];

      return {
        id: shell.pid
      }
    });

    return Promise.resolve(shells);
  }

  create(data, params) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current)));
    }
    let hostname=params.query.hostname
    let port = params.query.port
    const id = _.uniqueId();

    this.shells[id] = spawn('mongo', ['--host', hostname, '--port', port]);

    return Promise.resolve({id});
  }
}
module.exports = function() {
  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  let service =new ShellService()

  return service;
};
```

Once registered as a Feathers service you can then use `app.service('shells').find().then(shellInfo => )`.

Comment: Where should I call 'app.service('shells').find()' in my SocketService class? It doesn't have app instance in the class scope.

Comment: You can set the app in the `setup` method: https://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html#the-setup-method